# Rotated backups with snapshot on Ubuntu with email notifications

Tags: backup

Is there a package for backing up folders in Ubuntu with email notifications. I have looked at rsnapshot but it does not have email notifications.

Answer (score 1):

`cron` emails you the results of the jobs it runs, if they have any output, so if you run rsnapshot as a cron job and have installed a mail server ( such as postfix ), then you will get any output.